# Como puedo concatenar dos campos para una lista desplegable en Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Tengo una lista desplegable, pero esta me muestra unicamente el valor de una columna, tengo una tabla que se llama servicios, el primer campo se llama nombre y el segundo se llama version, Ejemplo

```
Nombre  
Pgsql    

Version  
9.1
```

Muestro la lista desplegable con el siguiente codigo.

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_servicio', 
                   'Servicio', 
                    App\Servicios::pluck('version', 'id')->toArray(),       
                    null, 
                   ['class'=>'chosen']) !!}
```

Debido a esto he tenido que escribir en el campo version, el valor tambien del tipo para que los usuarios lo puedan visualizar, Alguien me podria indicar como podria concatenar los campos nombre y los campos version por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para armar el texto de cada elemento de la lista usando más de un campo de tu tabla, en tu consulta puedes concatenar los campos que necesitas y darle un alias al resultado y hacer referencia al alias que le asignaste.

Si tu motor de base de datos es MySQL, con la función **`CONCAT()`** puedes unir los campos `nombre` y `version`, incluso con un separador entre ellos, por ejemplo:

```
CONCAT(nombre, '-', version)
```

Tomando de referencia tu código para armar la lista, el cambio quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_servicio', 
               'Servicio', 
                App\Servicios::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(nombre, '-', version) AS nombre_version"), "id")->pluck('nombre_version', 'id')->toArray(),       
                null, 
               ['class'=>'chosen']) !!}
```

Con el código anterior, el resultado sería un arreglo como el siguiente:

```
[
    1 => "Pgsql - 9.1",
    ...
]
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Funciono a la perfeccion, a pesar de ser en PGSQL, Te agradezco muchisimo :)